# How to return temporary password and username using Boto3 for Redshift get_cluster_credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, boto3, psycopg2

I can print the `boto3.client.get_cluster_credentials` and see the `'DbUser: 'IAM:#####" and 'DbPassword'###########'` but not able to assign that to a variable.

I've tried to set in my connection string the `DbUser` and `DbPassword` from my function call but get error.  When I hard code the actual username and password it works but I need to get what AWS returns to me as temporary credentials:

```
client = boto3.client('redshift', region_name='us-east-1')
cluster_creds = client.get_cluster_credentials( DbUser=',dbuser', DbName='dbName', ClusterIdentifier='ClusterName', AutoCreate=False)
conn = psycopg2.connect("host='<clusername>.<randomKey>.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com' port='5439' user=cluster_cred['Dbuser'] password=cluster_creds['DbPassword'] dbname='databaseName'")
```

I changed the code to `user=cluster_creds.DbUser` and it passed however when I changed `password=cluster_creds.DbPassword` it failed to authenticate.

Comment: Where did you get the credentials? Are you talking about [Using IAM Authentication to Generate Database User Credentials - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/generating-user-credentials.html)? I couldn't find a boto3 command called `get_user_credentials()` — can you provide a link to the documentation?

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/redshift.html#Redshift.Client.get_cluster_credentials

Comment: Are you referring to `get_cluster_credentials()`? Can you show us more of your code, or describe what you are trying to do? For example, "Use `get_cluster_credentials()` to obtain a set of credentials, then login to Redshift via psycopg2 using those credentials"?

Comment: That's exactly right @John  client = boto3.client('redshift', region_name='us-east-1')  cluster_creds = client.get_cluster_credentials(
    DbUser=',dbuser',  DbName='dbName',
    ClusterIdentifier='ClusterName',
    AutoCreate=False)  conn = psycopg2.connect("host='<clusername>.<randomKey>.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com' port='5439' user=cluster_cred['Dbuser'] password=cluster_creds['DbPassword'] dbname='databaseName'")

Comment: @john sorry, I'm not good at formatting on here.  I know get_cluster_credentials() returns a dictionary.  I can print it and see the DbUser and DbPassword key, values but I can't get it to set to a variable or set it directly in my connection string.  i want to be able to get temporary username and password so I can create tables, copy csv files from s3 to redshift table.  I found out that if it works my auth. returns as public and not sure how that will affect table creation and copying data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is referencing variables within a string, so the value is not being substituted:

```py
conn = psycopg2.connect("host='<clusername>.<randomKey>.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com' port='5439' user=cluster_cred['Dbuser'] password=cluster_creds['DbPassword'] dbname='databaseName'")
```

Also, it should be `cluster_creds` (not `cluster_cred`) and `DbUser` (not `Dbuser`).

Here's code that worked for me:

```py
import boto3
import psycopg2

DB_NAME = '<DB-NAME>'
CLUSTER_IDENTIFIER = '<CLUSTER-IDENTIFIER>'
DB_USER = '<DB-USER>'
ENDPOINT = '<DB-NAME>.<RANDOM-KEY>.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com'

client = boto3.client('redshift', region_name='us-east-1')
cluster_creds = client.get_cluster_credentials(DbUser=DB_USER, DbName=DB_NAME, ClusterIdentifier=CLUSTER_IDENTIFIER, AutoCreate=False)
temp_user=cluster_creds['DbUser']
temp_password=cluster_creds['DbPassword']
conn = psycopg2.connect("host='" + ENDPOINT + "' port='5439' user=" + temp_user + " password=" + temp_password + " dbname='" + DB_NAME + "'")
```

If you are using Python 3.6+, then the last line can use prettier f-strings:

```py
conn = psycopg2.connect(f"host='{ENDPOINT}' port='5439' user={temp_user} password={temp_password} dbname='{DB_NAME}'")
```

You will need to substitute your values for `<VALUES>`.